# print a list without '' in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I am new in `python3`(and `python`, all together), and still reading the docs.
So, I am facing many small and silly problems.

Currently, I am facing a problem of printing a `list` in a line.

If I `print` it inside a `for loop`,

```
for n in range(1,4):
  print(self.lstCord[self.q][n])
```

the lstCord are of type `string`.

expectedly, I am getting:

```
0
1
2
```

But if I print as

```
 print(self.lstCord[self.q][1], self.lstCord[self.q][2], self.lstCord[self.q][3])
```

its printing as:

```
('1', '2', '3')
```

while I am looking for the output as:

```
 1 2 3
```

i.e. without `(`,`)`, `'` and `,` and in the same line.

How can i get this?

Comment: Are you certain you're using Python 3.x?

Comment: yes....I am running it using `python3 <jobname>`

Answer (score 1):

In Python3 print has become a function. That means you can do this

```
for n in range(1,4):
    print(self.lstCord[self.q][n], end=" ")
```

.. which will end the printing of each item with a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a ',' at the end of the print line in the first example:

```
for n in range(1,4):
  print(self.lstCord[self.q][n]),
```

this will print all the list in the same line.

In the second example you get () because you are printing a tuple. If you remove the () you would get the same result.

Comment: That doesn't look like Python 3 to me.

Comment: Neither does the question.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich right, I forgot about it while writing the answer. I thought he only wanted to fix his code to print on a single line, and just modified slightly the code provided.